# I tried to import an external forex data and can't turn it into an xts object

Tags: r, import, time-series, xts, import-from-excel

I tried to import an excel file as an `xts` object but I encountered this message

> character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

I tried using csv format for my external data files but it didn't work and it seems like none of the other existing answers are able to solve my problem

Here are my codes and result

```
CNY <- read_excel("data/RAW.xlsx", sheet = "CNY") #Import external data
CNY
# A tibble: 9,845 x 2
X__1                 Line
<dttm>              <dbl>
 1 1981-01-02 00:00:00  1.53
 2 1981-01-05 00:00:00  1.54
 3 1981-01-06 00:00:00  1.53
 4 1981-01-07 00:00:00  1.53
 5 1981-01-08 00:00:00  1.53
 6 1981-01-09 00:00:00  1.54
 7 1981-01-12 00:00:00  1.54
 8 1981-01-13 00:00:00  1.54
 9 1981-01-14 00:00:00  1.54
10 1981-01-15 00:00:00  1.54
# ... with 9,835 more rows
CNY <- as.xts(CNY)

Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...) : 
character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

I expect CNY to be an xts object as if I used the `getSymbols` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work?

```
myxts <- xts(CNY$Line, order.by = CNY$X__1)
```